# Modify Parent Class based on Checkbox state

Tags: jquery, html, css

Still totally a noob with JS, but I'm making a modal window, it will have three states: hidden, hover, and inline.

There will be multiple instances of the window - each with different content.

I was able to "borg cube" something together and it's getting close to what I need but I can't figure out how to add the checkbox states I need.

Basically I want to add a class inline to the parent span when a checkbox on a modal is clicked.  It needs to remove the .hide when clicked as well.  If the box isn't clicked or when it's unchecked it should set the .hide class to the parent span.

I found some code that looks at the checkboxes but couldn't figure out how to integrate it:

```
$a('.switch-checkbox').change(function(){
 if($(this).is(":checked")) {
  this.parentElement.classList.add("inline");
  this.parentElement.classList.remove("hide");
  this.parentElement.classList.remove("hover");
 } else {
  this.parentElement.classList.add("hide");
  this.parentElement.classList.remove("inline");
 }
});
```

I've been playing with it in Codepen here:

https://codepen.io/axiomwebworks/pen/RwNbajy

Any help would be appreciated. I know I'm jumping in the deeper end considering how new I am to JS, I'm currently working through a great course on Udemy so I hope to keep getting better - Thanks -Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got this to what you were after and you were close. I used the code you gave and changed a few things. Since you were using jquery, I also used jquery methods inside the `change` function. Also, not only just jquery but pure js, you can `toggle`/`toggleClass` to add or remove classes. Try the code below. If anything it might help get you on the right track.

```js
let mantra = document.querySelectorAll(".mantra-link"), 
toggleHover = function() {
  [].map.call(mantra, function(elem) { });
  this.classList.remove("inline");
  this.classList.add("hover");
  this.classList.toggle("hide");
};

[].map.call(mantra, function(elem) {       
  elem.addEventListener("click", toggleHover, false);
});

$('.switch-checkbox').on('change', function() {
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
     $(this)
      .parent('aside')
      .parent('span')
      .toggleClass("inline hide hover");
   }
});
```

```css
.mantra-link{
  postion: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  border: solid red;
}
aside{
  background-color: white;
}

.inline aside{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.hovercard p{
  width: 100%;
}
.hide aside {
  display: none; /* Need this in case it's not hovering */
  visibility: hidden;
}
.hover aside{
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2.25m;
  background-color: white; 
  border: solid 1px gray;
  padding: 20px;
}
.inline{
  width: 100% ;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: blue solid 1px ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="kyu-library-steps">
  <h3 class="kyu-library-tag-heading">Instructions</h3>
  <ol class="kyu-library-steps-list">
    <li class="kyu-library-step">
      <div class="kyu-library-text"> <span class="mantra-link hide">Chant the <a href="#">Guru Ram Das Mantra </a> 
        <aside class="hovercard">
          <p>Lots of content about Mantra.</p>
          <span class="kyul-embed mantra-inline">Show mantra inline</span> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox" id="myswitch" unchecked>
          <label class="switch-labels" for="myswitch"></label>
        </aside>
        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima blanditiis consequuntur animi in quos aperiam voluptates eveniet possimus libero ipsa. Eaque, quisquam! Commodi, sit? Quod dignissimos illo voluptatem dolorem fuga?
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="kyu-library-step">
      <div class="kyu-library-text"> <span class="mantra-link hide">Chant the <a href="#">Guru Ram Das Mantra </a> 
        <aside class="hovercard">
          <p>Lots of content about Mantra.</p>
          <span class="kyul-embed mantra-inline">Show mantra inline</span> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox" id="myswitch" checked>
          <label class="switch-labels" for="myswitch"></label>
        </aside>
        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima blanditiis consequuntur animi in quos aperiam voluptates eveniet possimus libero ipsa. Eaque, quisquam! Commodi, sit? Quod dignissimos illo voluptatem dolorem fuga?
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="kyu-library-step">
      <div class="kyu-library-text"> <span class="mantra-link hide">Chant the <a href="#">Guru Ram Das Mantra </a> 
        <aside class="hovercard">
          <p>Lots of content about Mantra.</p>
          <span class="kyul-embed mantra-inline">Show mantra inline</span> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox" id="myswitch" unchecked>
          <label class="switch-labels" for="myswitch"></label>
        </aside>
        </span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima blanditiis consequuntur animi in quos aperiam voluptates eveniet possimus libero ipsa. <span class="mantra-link hide">Chant the <a href="#">Guru Ram Das Mantra </a> 
        <aside class="hovercard">
          <p>Lots of content about Mantra.</p>
          <span class="kyul-embed mantra-inline">Show mantra inline</span> 
          <input type="checkbox" name="switch" class="switch-checkbox" id="myswitch" unchecked>
          <label class="switch-labels" for="myswitch"></label>
        </aside>
        </span>Eaque, quisquam! Commodi, sit? Quod dignissimos illo voluptatem dolorem fuga?
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</section>
```